# How to convert Strings to into a phone number

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I've been stuck on this questions for so long this is the question:

Write a function that takes a string as an argument and returns the phone number 
corresponding to that string as the result. 
The phone number should also be a string. 
The conversion rules are the standard word to phone number rules:

> 'a', 'b' or 'c' maps to 2
>
> 'd', 'e' or 'f' maps to 3
>
> 'g', 'h' or 'i' maps to 4
>
> 'j', 'k', or 'l' maps to 5
>
> 'm', 'n', or 'o' maps to 6
>
> 'p', 'q', 'r', or 's' maps to 7
>
> 't', 'u', or 'v' maps to 8
>
> 'w', 'x', 'y', or 'z' maps to 9.

Basically I tried

```
for char in word:
    if char == 'a' or char == 'b' or char == 'c':
    print 2,
```

and so on but when I call the function `strng_to_num("apples")`
the output is `2 7 7 5 3 7` where I want `'277537'`. Is there anyway to remove the spaces?

Comment: Hint: `ord(c)` returns the ASCII code of a character. If z, subtract one. If larger than q, subtract one. Subtract base, integer divide by three.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
def string_to_num(in_str):
    try:
        translationdict = str.maketrans("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz","22233344455566677778889999")
    except AttributeError:
        import string
        translationdict = string.maketrans("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz","22233344455566677778889999")

    out_str = in_str.lower().translate(translationdict)
    return out_str
```

The algorithm ooga alluded to in the comment to the question is definitely faster but requires a bit more intense thought than just building a translation dict. This way works for python2 or python3, but here are the relevant docs for `maketrans` in [Python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans) and [Python3](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans)

Comment: @DSM d'oh. Fixed. Dunno why I thought `str.translate` worked in-place (that'd be a feat eh?)

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'maketrans'

Comment: @karna Aww that's right, `maketrans` is on `string` not `str` in Python2. I'll edit...

Comment: This fails with `NameError: global name 'string' is not defined` in python2.

Comment: @JohnB did you `import string`?

Comment: No, but neither did you.

Answer (score 3):

Don't print each number individually. Instead, add them to a list, and print them all together at the end:

```
phone_num = []
for char in word:
    if char == 'a' or char == 'b' or char == 'c':
       phone_num.append('2')
    elif char == 'd' or char == 'e' or char == 'f':
       phone_num.append('3')
    ...
print ''.join(phone_num)
```

You can make your if statements a little simpler by writing:

```
if char in 'abc':
    ...
elif char in 'def':
    ...
```

Comment: This fails with TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found

Comment: @RobinHood I changed the `phone_num.append` lines to append strings instead of ints. You could also leave them as ints if you prefer, but change the join statement to `print ''.join(str(i) for i in phone_num)`, which will go through the digits and convert them to strings before outputting.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dictionary and iterate through each character, then compare to each dictionary key.

```
def phone(arg):
    num_dict = {'abc': "2",
               'def': "3",
               'ghi': "4",
               'jkl': "5",
               'mno': "6",
               'pqrs': "7",
               'tuv': "8",
               'wxyz': "9" }
    string = ""
    for c in arg:
            for k in num_dict.keys():
                    if c in k:
                            string += num_dict[k]
    return string
```

Comment: Definitely better write out the whole dictionary (`{'a':'2','b':'2','c':'2', ... "z":'9'}`) and then use a list comp and `str.join` e.g. `"".join[num_dict[ch] for ch in arg]`

Comment: @AdamSmith Define "better" please, and how.  "You did it wrong", is not exactly a helpful comment.  I wrote the dict that way because I don't like repeating myself.  You already have the answer man, don't beat mine up without explaining yourself.

Comment: John B: "Better" in this case meaning both faster to write, faster to run, and more easily readable to the next guy who has to maintain your code. `num_dict = dict( zip("abc...wxyz", "222...9999") )`

Comment: Actually, I timed it and they are the same.  Your way uses more memory.  Faster to write something with more characters? Hmmm...and I think mine is easier to read.

Comment: John: either you're fabricating results to try and discredit me or you typed one or the other function wrong. My results show 1,000,000 iterations of your function taking 21.2954s and 1,000,000 iterations of my function taking 3.6257s on the string `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`. The only modification I made to either script is to change your `for c in arg` to `for c in arg.lower()` to match my type checking.

Comment: John: if you change your function as I suggested, it runs in 6.3846s

Comment: The reason I mentioned any change at all is your repeated membership tests. They're MUCH slower than a hash mapping (`if c in k` compared to `num_dict[c]`) so I assumed your timing would be screwed up because of it. I'll take a minuscule increase in memory footprint for 700% speed increase, thank you :)

Comment: Really? Not sure where you got your numbers but when running the function 1,000,000 times using `time`, I got 12.171s using the method you suggested and 12.260s using mine.  So, in a world where you'd actually need to run the function a million times, I'll take readability, less memory, less external functions and not repeating myself over being 89 milliseconds faster.

Comment: John: As I said, I'm sure something is being mistyped. It's certainly not an issue either way. I find your code VASTLY less readable than mine, slightly more memory-conservative, but also 7 times slower. I'm not sure what external functions I'd be using that you're not (how is `zip` an external function if `dict.keys` isn't?) but however you'd like to write it is okay by me: I'm just trying to help your code get better, it doesn't matter one bit to me if you take my advice or not.

Comment: John: the reason I implemented `str.translate` in my answer is because it's typically MUCH faster than a list comp, which in turn is MUCH faster than repeated membership checks. You don't have to agree with me, it's not really a point of contention. In your code, you may feel free to write whatever you like -- that's the beauty of programming after all!

Comment: Adam: Yep, and another thing I love about about programming is defending code against baseless criticisms.  Also, I find it's typically not a good idea to claim something is "MUCH" faster for a situation without comparing speeds properly.

Comment: John: certainly not baseless, since "comparing speeds properly" will show the results I have, thereabouts. Here, if you prefer, run it yourself http://codepad.org/gU4z9BzB but as I say I'm not really interested in trying to CONVINCE you that your code isn't as good as it can be, merely wondering why you're so certain that IT IS?

Comment: Adam: http://codepad.org/NpggnxRl actually shows my method as being faster that what you suggested.

Comment: Interesting! Though I trust `timeit` more than successive calls to `time.time`. I do wonder what causes the discrepancy. I don't have the time or energy to dig deeper to find out :). Certainly part of it is building the `range(1,100001)` generator, which is possibly memoized by the interpreter which increases the speed of subsequent calls. Regardless that's not ALL of it. Worth a look by someone, certainly :)

Comment: The reason our results were different was primarily because the length of the string you fed the methods in your test was four times longer than the `apples` string I fed it like the example the OP gave.  So in a case where you'd need to iterate that many times with a long string, both your suggestion and answer would indeed be much faster.

Comment: Guys, this has been an interesting discussion! I'm impressed by the cleverness and concise elegance of @AdamSmith 's code, though I feel that JohnB 's is a little easier for a beginner to understand (and the OP is clearly a newcomer to python). But I feel compelled to point out that the OP had already managed to solved the problem of mapping letters to numbers. His/her actual question was in regards to a way to "remove the spaces" from the final output. =)